# How this code prints in reverse order in linked list

Tags: recursion

What does the following function do for a given Linked List with first node as head?

```
 void fun1(struct node* head)

 {

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    fun1(head->next);

    printf("%d  ", head->data);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly as if you had pushed the list elements into a stack and then popped each off and printed it until the stack was empty. Although using the call stack rather than a data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this:

```
head= |data=a
      |next= |data=b
             |next= |data=c
                    |next=NULL
```

Now you call fun1(head):

```
call fun1(head):
     calls fun1(head->next):
          calls fun1(head->next->next):
               calls fun1(head->next->next->next):
                    returns, because head->next->next->next is NULL
               prints c (from head->next->next->data)
          prints b (from head->next->data)
     prints a (from head->data)
```

PS: You might find it helpful to learn how to step through your code for this kind of question: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/debug-c-program-using-gdb/